# Defining Octave Functions

Tags: function, octave

I am working on a school project with Octave for calculating and plotting velocity/acceleration graphs.

I have been trying to create a subplot function so that I won't have to hardcore it for every subplot as such

```
subplot(3, 1, 1);
plot(time, accn);
grid;
title('Acceleration vs Time')
xlabel('Time, (s)')
ylabel('Acceleration, (m/s^2)')

subplot(3, 1, 2);
plot(time, velocity);
grid;
title('Velocity vs Time');
xlabel('Time, (s)');
ylabel('Velocity, (m/s)');
```

Is it possible to create a function akin to this

```
subplot = subplotFunction(row, column, xaxis, yaxis, header, xaxisLabel, 
yaxisLabel)
subplot(3, row, column);
plot(xaxis, yaxis);
grid;
title('header')
xlabel('xaxisLabel')
ylabel('yaxisLabel')
endfunction
```

And then call it like this?

```
subplot = subplotFunction(1, 1, time, accn, 'Acceleration vs Time', 'Time, (s)', 'Acceleration, (m/s^2)')
```

I am quite new to using functions so my apologies :(

Comment: Have you tried to do it this way (without the `subplot = subplotFunction` part but with a correct function declaration)?

Comment: Yes I have tried running the function method but it returns error: 'row' undefined near line 2 column 27. What would a correct function declaration in this scenario look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
1;

function subplotFunction(row, column, idx, xaxis, yaxis, header, xaxisLabel, yaxisLabel)
  subplot (row, column, idx);
  plot (xaxis, yaxis);
  grid on;
  title (header)
  xlabel (xaxisLabel)
  ylabel (yaxisLabel)
endfunction

subplotFunction (3, 1, 1, 1:10, 11:20, "foo", "bar", "baz")
subplotFunction (3, 1, 2, 1:10, 11:20, "huhu", "haha", "hoho")
x = linspace (0, 10, 100);
subplotFunction (3, 1, 3, x, sin(x), "world", "boo", "doo")

print ("out.png")
```

gives

[image: output]